# Problem on limit of Lagrange's form of remainder

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, derivatives

For the function
$f(x) = \begin{cases}
    \ e^{\frac{-1}{x^2}} &    x\neq0,\\\\
    0 & x=0
\end{cases}$

Let $R_n(x)$ denote Lagrange's form of remainder. Is $\lim_{n\to\infty} R_n(x)=0$

Lagrange's form of remainder is
$R_n(x)=f(x)-\sum_{k=0}^{n}\frac1{k!}f^{(k)}(a)(x-a)^k$.

But I  am stuck on calculating the  $n+1^{th}$ derivative of the give function and thereby applying limits.

Please help me in proving or disproving the given statement.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. What's $a$ here? Is $limR_n(x)=0$ supposed to be $\lim_{x\to a} R_n(x)=0$ ? Is it $\lim_{n\to\infty} R_n(x)=0$ ? Pointwise? How is "Lagrange's form" relevant? $R_n(x)=f(x)-\sum_{k=0}^{n}\frac1{k!}f^{(k)}(a)(x-a)^k$ regardless of whether or not you observe that there is some $\xi(x)$ such that yada yada. And none of the limits I've mentioned depend on $\xi(x)$.

Comment: Lagrange's form is given in the question.  We need to calculate it's limit pointwise. Sorry, I misunderstood the formula. I will make changes

Comment: What you've written is not Lagrange's form of the remainder.

Comment: I don't know much about Lagrange's remainder. I got these formulae from another site .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you've written as $R_n(x)$ is Tailor ramainder. The Lagrange form of the remainder comes from a theorem that ensures there is a point $c$ between $a$ and $x$ such that: $$ R_n(x) = \frac{f^{(n+1)}(c)}{(n+1)!} (x-a)^{n+1} $$
Then you shall prove that the expression at the right converges to $0$, which requires finding a general bound for the term $f^{(n+1)}(c)$.

However, the function you defined as $f$ is a classic example in analysis as a function that is $C^n$ but the Taylor polynomial centered at $0$ doesn't converges to $f$ at any point other than $x=0$. This is proved by checking that, for every $n$, $f^{(n)}(x) = p_n(\frac{1}{x^2})e^{\frac{-1}{x^2}}$, for some polynomial $p_n$.

I hope my answer is something like what you wanted, and that it helped you.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I got it